# System to pair a person to another person

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, web

Me and my group are doing a service project. We are shaky on programming in (**php/javascript/wordpress**) Interested first in learning so doing by hand is preferred to a plug-in.

They need a system to match a sponsor to a person who needs a gift for x-mas. They said something like  "kind of like the Amazon Check-Out"

A sponsor would go into a database of people, read descriptions of the people and "check-out" essentially pairing the two people.

Where would we start?

Comment: Probably the most broad question I have ever read. Probably better to separate your requirements into a set of web views for a customer and then post questions here one by one with any struggles you have. I recommend reading into HTML Forms and PHP first to get data processing in your info set, and then PHP with MySQL for info on ow to save/fetch data from storage.

Comment: "Where would we start?" By defining the software requirement specification. You could then analyse it to estimate what parts/components are involved, to be able to then implement them and eventually see for which ones of them a ready made solution can be used (libraries) and for which you need to write new code. Just a suggestion.